# How to explain the closing of a performance gap in a descriptive trend analysis?

Tags: correlation, inference, group-differences

I haven't used inferential statistics in a few years, so I am blanking on a simple question.

I ran a descriptive trend analysis on assessment results for a school district, disaggregated for group-level characteristics like household income. I created a chart for those who scored "Demonstrating" (the highest level) from both low-income households and mid- to high-income households. I was surprised to see (below) a gap in performance close between the two groups over a three-year period.

[image: Students Who Scored "Demonstrating" on Readiness Assessments by Household Income]

I thought about it and decided to see if the number of students in each group had changed. The next chart (below) confirms the group sizes also changed over three years.

[image: Number of Students Who Took the Readiness Assessment by Household Income]

My first thought is that, other than exploring qualitative reasons for why the group sizes changed, this could be explained with a bivariate correlation formula. Would this be correct, or would there be a more suitable inferential method to explain why the performance gap closed?

Comment: For both groups to converge on worse and worse performance is not the kind of "closing of a gap" that any educator would have in mind!  But I'm afraid your work is being hindered by use of this binary variable -- "Demonstrated Readiness" or "Did Not."  You could no doubt reveal more about the two populations' progress or regress if you had access to the underlying scale scores and could then run an ANOVA by year and income level.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have access to three different assessment scores but only a binary variable indicating income (all at an aggregated level). And you're right about the gap closure not being in a favorable direction. :(